# How can i use mouse to move the robot in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to make a robot, which will move like a robot in video games. i.e when i move the mouse right side, it should rotate its face to right direction according to how much mouse has rotated, and when some keys in keyboard is pressed it should move forward and backward like in video games.
Well i have seen how i can specify a specific task fro given keyboard, but how to do it with a mouse?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16814/how-can-i-use-mouse-to-move-the-robot-in-gazebo?/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For the keyboard, you could load the [KeyboardGUIPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/plugins/KeyboardGUIPlugin.hh), which publishes key presses on Gazebo topic `~/keyboard/keypress` and make a plugin which subscribes to it.

For the mouse, you can add filters to catch when mouse events are registered on the GUI. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/chapulina/gazebo_plugins/src/dd9c7d7e7291b469984f22d5cbe3a13c1a905c39/Dominoes/DominoesPlugin.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#DominoesPlugin.cc-101)'s an example.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1